# Split array into groups of different sizes

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to split an array into groups of different sizes.

```
let objects = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

let sizes = [3,2,4]
```

The output should be [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14], [15]]

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @mag_zbc I know how to split an array into groups of the same size, and am able to do that without any issues, but I haven't managed to find a way to split an array into groups of different sizes... which is why I'm asking how to do it.

Comment: @JamesAnderson I don't believe there is anything wrong with your question. However, it might be downvoted because you didn't try anything yourself (or at least didn't prove it) and just expect an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact solution for your problem but to split the array into different sizes you can use something like below:

```
  var index = 0
  var count = 0

for size in sizes{
    let newArray = objects[index..<size+index]
    index = count > 0 ? size + sizes[count-1] : size   //index = 3
    count = count + 1
    print(newArray)
}
```

This will split array into group of different sizes. You can modify the code to complete all the array elements. This basically loops once over the sizes Array.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I don't understand what is wrong with the question? I spent the best part of two hours trawling through Stack Overflow to try and find a solution before posting this. Clearly I couldn't find anything that would point me in the right direction, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: "Clearly I couldn't find anything that would point me in the right direction" That's not at all clear, actually. Perhaps the most asked Swift question is the classic "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value". [Searching StackOverflow for that phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unexpectedly+found+nil+while+unwrapping+an+optional+value) gives 4,339 matches! The premise that "OP posted a question, therefore surely OP did their background research" is not even close to true. If you did background research, that's great! You should share it in your question

Comment: @JamesAnderson There are huge organizational difficulties with organizing an online resource for free help like SO. At a minimum, the community here expects some demonstration of background effort and an attempt to self-serve. If you watch the [swift] tag for (or most tags here, honestly), you'll see that there's a constant inflow of people posting "do my work for me" questions, expecting that this site is some kind of free code consultancy service. To differentiate yourself from such people, you'll want to show your 2 hours of research